# How to get rid of error "haxm accelerator" in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I installed Eclipse and it showed an error about HAXM accelerator not being installed.
I've already enabled VT-x in boot settings, but still I'm not able to install the HAXM accelerator.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Some antivirus options prevent `HAXM` installation. ie: Avast : settings (parameters) tab -> troubleshooting (depannage) : you should uncheck "enable hardware-assisted virtualization" ("activer l'assistance a la virtualization").

Comment: Real thanx will be to accept the answer. Happy to help :)